# matrix class template，the multiplication or addition of different types of matrices

Tags: c++

I am writing a matrix class template. I want to implement the multiplication or addition of different types of matrices（ for example, between real and imaginary matrices ）, but I cannot access the data members of another type of matrix. How should I solve this problem?

```
template <class Type>
class Matrix
{
    Type** p_data; //Represents matrix data
    int row, col; //Represents the number of rows and columns of the matrix
public:
    Matrix(int r, int c);
    ~Matrix(); 
    Matrix(Type *data, int row, int col);
    Type* operator[] (int i); 
    // Overload [], for Matrix object M, can be accessed by M [I] [J] to 
    // access the i + 1 line, the J + 1 column element
    Matrix &operator = (const Matrix& m); 
    // Overload =, implement matrix overall assignment, if the row / column does not wait, 
    // return space and reassign
    bool operator == (const Matrix& m) const; //Overload ==, determined whether the matrix is ​​equal
    template <class Type1>
    Matrix operator + (const Matrix<Type1>& m) const;
    // Overload +, complete matrix addition, can assume 
    // that the two matrices meet the addition conditions (the rows, the columns are equal)
    template <class Type1>
    Matrix operator * (const Matrix<Type>& m) const; 
    // Overload *, complete matrix multiplication, can assume that two matrices meet multiplication 
    // conditions (this.col = m.row)
    template <class Type1>
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out,Matrix<Type1>& c);
};
template<class Type>
template <class Type1>
Matrix<Type> Matrix<Type>::operator + (const Matrix<Type1>& m) const{
    Matrix<Type> res(row,col);
    for(int i=0;i<row;++i)
        for(int j=0;j<col;++j)
            res.p_data[i][j] =p_data[i][j] + m.p_data[i][j];  //  error in this line
    return res;
}
```

Comment: You can make them friends or expose necessary API to achieve that without friend declarations.

Comment: I bet that the users of such matrix library will tend, when applicable within the particular domain, to use the same type `T` to represent a matrix element: *mathematically* speaking the set of complex numbers contains the set of real numbers which in turn contains the set of relative numbers.

Comment: It's right that the users tend to use the same type T. But in some cases, it's convient that this function is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [friend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) declaration

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
  template <typename U>
  friend class Matrix;

  // ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have solved this problem by following your suggestiion.

Comment: @zanilia Welcome to SO. Please take a look at this page: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @zanilia Thank you, I upvoted your question +1. Thank you too Bob__53